# Return the index of a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, search, methods, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a method that searches for a value in a 2D array. Upon finding the value I want to return the value's index. Is there a way to return the index of the value without returning another array?

Comment: If you are using a simple loop just add a counter(int). The fun begins when you figured the logic out by yourself.

Comment: Return a string formed by `row_index,column_index`. Now split again to get the index of value in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to not return an array nor string with both integers, you could create a class with two attributes (x,y), and return an instance of that class. But I don't see why you would do this

Class be looking like:

```
public class MyIndex{
    int x;
    int y;

    public MyIndex(int x, int y){
       this.x=x;
       this.y=y;
    }

    public int getX() {return x;}
    public void setX(int x) {this.x = x;}
    public int getY() {return y;}
    public void setY(int y) {this.y = y;}
}
```

Or use Point class from package java.awt

Comment: Do you have to make the class or is there already one made in the Java library?

Comment: @Alex I doubt there is.

Comment: There's a [`Pair`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) class in Apache Commons.

Comment: Theres also [java.awt.Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)

Comment: Oh, I forgout about Point, you can use that

Answer (score -1):

You have no other solution but to return the two indices:

```
public static int[] find(int a[][], int val) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < a[i].length ; ++j) {
            if(a[i][j] == val) {
                return new int[] {i, j};
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Read OP question again *Is there a way to return the index of the value **without returning another array**?*

Comment: Basically, the answer is no. You can create any object containing the information, but you still need those two indices. It is the minimum required information.

Comment: Is there a class that does this?

Comment: Woa, is your question: how to represent a pair in one object??